# How to Configure validation logic for passwords in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have created a new MVC project (default MVC5 Individual User Accounts template) and I have made changes to IdenitityConfig.cs

```
manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 1,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
            RequireDigit = false,
            RequireLowercase = false,
            RequireUppercase = false,
        };
```

But still while registration it gives an error  "The Password must be at least 6 characters long."

But I have changed length to 1.

Comment: What authentication was the project created with by default? Individual User Accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not passing the viewmodel validation.

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    //[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

If you remove this line `[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]`, you will not have this issue.

Comment: Yeah that's it, remember to change it for other view models too (eg: ResetPasswordViewModel)

Comment: Thanks it worked ! Again I want to make change at manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true; as false. I am facing problem everytime register and try to use authorization it asks me to login in again